# Cannot Alter Table Constraint on Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

anyone knows, i tried so many times to use alter table constraint in my mysql sql.

So i want to alter table constraint to add validation in gender column :

```
alter table jewerly 
add constraint checkGender CHECK(Gender='Male' OR Gender='female');
```

is that right ? i dont know what is the problem but it always return empty result on my mysql. why ?

i read from another thread, it said that is normal if return empty result.

but i try to export my sql and i see no contraint query added on my sql.

anyone knows the problem ?

======

Note : it marked as duplicate question, but the last thread only has sollution for checking gender constraint, how about if i want to add another constraint ? the constraint always missing after we add it.

Comment: Looks like [Add constraint on values , Mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725716/add-constraint-on-values-mysql)

Comment: Note : it marked as duplicate question, but the last thread only has sollution for checking gender constraint, how about if i want to add another constraint ? the constraint always missing after we add it.

Comment: You add the second constraint in the same fashion as you add the first.  The technique given in the original answer (the question you duplicated) needs to be applied for each constraint you want to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL does not suport check constraints and that is why you dont see it even on SHOW CREATE TABLE

Comment: so, how for me to add constraint to my sql ?
i have added manually and import to mysql,  and i check again with export, and i cannot found the constraint that i add manually ..

Comment: @rayejoe Use `ENUM` or trigger as in link I posted before

Comment: you can definitely add constraints, but this check / validation wont be run. You could try inserting a row that violates the check constraint and mysql will not throw you any errors, it will accept the record. You may have to either do validation in the code before you perform the insert.

Comment: @iad2025 helo bro thanks before, i have read your post about enum, but honestly i am not understand how to use that, i am new in mysql, can you give me example how to use that related to my code?

Comment: @SKY i think so, that that validation cannot run if we add in constraint, but this is my college project, they ask us to include constraint in our sql,, but if i add constraint in my sql and import to mysql, the constraint will missing again and we cannot found it if we import our sql. So how to add constraint stay in my sql ? does not matter it cannot run the validation, but i really need to add the constraint for our college project.

Comment: @rayejoe alter table jewerly modify gender enum('M','F') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'M';

Comment: @sky yes the case for checking gender constraint is solved. but how about another constraint? example if we want to validate with another condition, the constraint always missing after we add it.

Comment: Yes, because mysql does not support check constraints, you will have to do it either by changing the data type of the column to `ENUM` and specifying all the valid values in it.

Comment: @SKY thank you very much,,, your answer very usefull.. but sorry sir, for the last question, can you help me to modify validation with enum for : inputted for productID format must like : PR[xxx], xxx means the number... if we use constraint, it will be like 'PR[0-9][0-9][0-9]', can you help me with enum ? thanks

Comment: @SKY i tried this but not work : alter table jewelry modify jewelid enum('PR[0-9][0-9][0-9]') NOT NULL;

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this would be to create a gender table (id, gender) and use a foreign key on your jewelry table to reference the gender table.

Add a gender_id column to your jewelry table, and then create a foreign key on your jewelry table.

```
ALTER TABLE jewelry ADD CONSTRAINT fk_jewelry_gender 
FOREIGN KEY (gender_id) REFERENCES gender (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Comment: its good sollution, but my project has a rule that we must create table characteristic as they won, if i use your answers it seems that i will break the project rule. :( .